# AndEngine application always crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

i just started with AndEngine, wrote my first code and i have problem. Eclipse does not show any errors, but the app crashes on AVD. here is the code:

```
package com.example.simplepool;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity
{
private Camera camera;
private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
{
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, 
    new FillResolutionPolicy(), camera);
    return engineOptions;
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources()
{

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene()
{
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
    return scene;
}
}
```

logcat:

```
   03-02 05:56:08.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1451): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 100
```

i think i do not have problem in manifest, i did not change MainActivity name or whatever.
when i launch it it crashes after it changed screen orientation to landscape, so the activity starts normally.

thanks for responses

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: Is this a phone or emulator?

Comment: Actually, i had to set when i was creating AVD to use host GPU true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i had to set when i was creating AVD to use host GPU true

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).